# Cannot convert in to int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

So I am making the card game of war and I am trying to get each card that I create using a 2d array into an array list. However, I keep coming across the issue that the 'cannot convert int to int[][]' error keeps popping up. Since I made currentCard a 2d int, I'm quite of confused as to why this is happening.

**I am VERY beginner at this while coding thing, and I'm sure that this code is riddled with errors, but please be nice!

```
int[][] cards = new int[5][14];
int[][] currentCard;
Image[][] cardImage = new Image[5][14];

public void init()

{
    addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
    addMouseListener((MouseListener) this);
    for(int suit=1;suit<=4;suit++)
    {
        for(int cardNum=1;cardNum<=13;cardNum++)
        {
            cardImage[suit][cardNum]= new ImageIcon("H:\\Downloads\\classic-cards\\" + suit + "-" + cardNum + ".png").getImage();
        }
    }

    for(int suit=1;suit<=4;suit++)
    {
        for(int cardNum=1;cardNum<=13;cardNum++)
        {
            currentCard= cards[suit][cardNum]; //error here- says i cannot convert from int to int[][]
            cardList.add(currentCard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need `addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);` you can directly do `addKeyListener(this)`. The same apply for `addMouseListener`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear,

`currentCard` represent an `int[][]` as per it declaration :

```
int[][] currentCard;
```

However, when you try to affect it, you give it an `int` :

```
currentCard = cards[suit][cardNum];
```

because `cards` is also an `int[][]` and you try to assign to `currentCard` the int at the position `[suit][cardNum]`.

I'm pretty sure what you want is to declare `currentCard` as a simple `int` as it make non sense for a variable named `currentCard` to hold multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

`int[][] currentCard` means that the field `currentCard` is a matrix, but actually you want to use it as one value in the `cards` matrix.

`cards[3][4]` for example will return a single integer value, if you want it extracted in a single variable, the one should be of the same type - `int` - the type of the value, and not `int[][]` - the type of the structure

TL;DR - change to `int currentCard`

Answer (score 0):

Since `cards` is a two dimension array, when you access `cards[suit][cardNum]` it returns an `int`. However, `currentCard` is defined as an `int[][]`. So, `currentCard` should be defined as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to define currentCard as int instead of int [][]

So change the second instruction to

```
int currentCard;
```

Anyway you can not cast int to matrix

Answer (score 0):

I think I guess what you want to do, you expect to have the currentCard as some pair of integers: one for the suit and one for the cardNum. It is going to be very difficult to handle this as one single variable if you dont define a class Card (probably the homework rules out the use of classes?).

If class Card {int Suit; int Num; } is ruled out, probably you can define currentCard as int[2]; and you cardList as a list of such arrays..

Answer (score 0):

```
currentCard= cards[suit][cardNum]; //Impossible
```

Exemple

```
int x;
int[][] matrix = new int[5][14];
matrix=x;//Impossible
```

but you can

```
currentCard[suit][cardNum]= cards[suit][cardNum];
```

or

```
currentCard= cards;
```